# android.os.Parcelable android.widget.GridView.onSaveInstanceState()' on a null?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-savedstate

I am making News app and I have Gridview inside fragment and I have implemented onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState when configuration changes.

below an error which I am getting

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp, PID: 5676
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.widget.GridView.onSaveInstanceState()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp.AllNewsFragmentTab.onCreateView(AllNewsFragmentTab.java:53)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:167)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
03-17 20:12:26.358 5676-5676/com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
and below my Fragment where I have implemented configuration changes

public class AllNewsFragmentTab extends Fragment {

```
public ArrayList<News> articleList;
ArrayList<Article> articleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public GridView gridView;
private View parentView;
private ArticleAdapter adapter;
Parcelable state;
```

// ...

// restore index and position

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_news_fragment_tab, container, false);
    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    articleList = new ArrayList<>();

    parentView = view.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    state = gridView.onSaveInstanceState();
    /**
     * Getting List and Setting List Adapter
     *
     *
     */


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

//                Snackbar.make(parentView, articleArrayList.get(position).getStatus() + " => " + articleArrayList.get(position).getTotalResults(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), NewsDetailActivity.class);

```
            i.putExtra("myDataKey", articleArrayList.get(position));
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.string_click_to_load, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();


    /**
     * Checking Internet Connection
     */
    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog;
        /**
         * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
         */
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_title));
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.string_getting_json_message));
        dialog.dismiss();



        //Creating an object of our api interface
        ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();

        /**
         * Calling JSON
         */
        Call<News> call = api.getAllNews();

        /**
         * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
         */
        call.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
                //Dismiss Dialog
                dialog.dismiss();

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    /**
                     * Got Successfully
                     */
                    // String articleList = String.valueOf(response.body());
                    News news = response.body();


                    articleArrayList.addAll(news.getArticles());


                    /**
                     * Binding that List to Adapter
                     */adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getActivity(), articleArrayList);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    if(state != null) {
                        gridView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
                    }

                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_some_thing_wrong, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    } else {
        Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_internet_connection_not_available, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return view;
}
```

}

```
below my all_news_fragment_tab.xml where I have declared my fragment

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It would seem that the `View` with ID `listView` is not in the `all_news_fragment_tab` layout. Are you sure that's the right ID?

Comment: @Mike M I have added  XML comment above please check it thanks

Comment: Do you have separate portrait and landscape layouts for your `Fragment`? Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding your project?

Comment: @Mike M. I have tried not working